# Gradio - Update View on Button Click

Tags: python, gradio, chromadb

I would like to find out how can I update this
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/entvZ.png) upon file upload or deletion.

If I upload a file, there should be another role for 'file c'. If I click on the cross, it should delete the relevant row.

I was thinking there could be a way for the vector database to be reloaded rather than reloading the page.

I first load my data (Document objects) with persist_directory and retrieve the file names as keys and ids as values as shown below:

```py
db = Chroma(persist_directory='./db',
            embedding_function=embeddings)
db_json = db.get()
db_json_dict = {}

for i in range(len(db_json['ids'])):
    file_id = db_json['ids'][i]
    file_name = db_json['metadatas'][i]['source']
    file_name_index = file_name.rfind('\\')
    if file_name_index > -1:
        file_name = file_name[file_name_index+1:]
    file_name_index = file_name.rfind('.')
    file_name = file_name[0:file_name_index]

    if db_json_dict.get(file_name) == None:
        db_json_dict[file_name] = [file_id]
    else:
        db_json_dict[file_name].append(file_id)
```

Then in my gr.Blocks(), I do a for loop to display each row with a delete button.

```py
for i in range(len(db_json_dict.keys())):
                with gr.Row():
                    gr.Markdown(list(db_json_dict.keys())[i])
                    button = gr.Button('❌')
                    label = gr.Label(value=list(db_json_dict.keys())[i],
                                     visible=False)
                    button.click(delete_doc, label)
```

Afterwards in the delete_doc function, it should delete from the collection and reload the page with the updates.

```py
def delete_doc(key):
    ids = db_json_dict.get(key['label'])
    db._collection.delete(ids=ids)
    #TODO: Refresh view
```

I am stuck here and would like to know the best way to update the view upon create/deletion.